# Symfony2 API test POST using YAML/Faker

Tags: api, symfony, yaml, fixtures, alice

I'm building a REST API using Symfony2. I am already using [Liip bundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle) for my functional tests together with [Alice](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle) and [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to genereate all the fixtures. However, I have little trouble when I want to directly test POST calls themselves as long JSON are included in the POST data, which made my functions quite long, ugly and unreadable.

I decided to move the fake JSON out of the class, converting them to YAML files and then loading them using Symfony's parser:

```
private function loadYaml($resource){
        $data = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/YAML/' . $resource . '.yml'));
        return $data;
}
```

This seems to work quite well, since I can easily convert them back to JSON objects and then use it in the call:

```
$postData = json_encode($this->loadYaml('newapplication'));
$this->client->request(
    'POST', 
    '/api/application/save/',
    array('data' => $postData), // The Request parameters
    array(), // Files
    array(),
    'mybody', // Raw Body Data
    true
);
```

My first question is: is this a right approach? Is there any bundle that I have missed which will make my life much easier?

My second question is wheter it will be possible to use Faker within this YAML constructions. On my fixtures, I call Faker functions (e.g. < firstName() >) that when fixtures are loaded automatically fill my entities with random but meaningful values. Would it be possible to use them in these YAML constructions?

Thanks a lot! ;)

Answer (score 0):

For your question about bundle, WebTestCase from Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase is really nice to do test on REST API in Symfony project.

In POST, data are in body and not has parameter. ([How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request))

Try

```
$this->client->request(
    'POST', 
    '/api/application/save/',
    array(), // The Request parameters
    array(), // Files
    array(),
    $postData, // Raw Body Data
    true
);
```

Comment: In our application, data is sent within the request parameters. I am using WebTestCase from Liip Bundle, which adds a few interesting features.